# 2 variables from select box and hidden input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I get 2 different variables from select box and hidden inputs in jquery, i.e:

```
<select name="startID[]" class="startID">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<input type="hidden" name="startText[]" value="Text1">

<br />

<select name="startID[]" class="startID">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<input type="hidden" name="startText[]" value="Text2">


<br />

<select name="startID[]" class="startID">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<input type="hidden" name="startText[]" value="Text3">
```

so I have 3 select boxes with 3 hidden inputs, how can I get the value of each select boxed and the text that is attached to? i.e: if I select like this:

```
Select item is 1 and text is Text1
Select item is 3 and text is Text2
Select item is 2 and text is Text3
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can not understand what do you want to achieve?

Comment: Your code makes it impossible to achieve that result. Every selectbox is exactly the same. You have to distinguish them from each other in some logic way..

Comment: I think there is some way, mentioned below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function getValues() {
    $('select').each(function (idx, el) {
        console.log("Select item is " + $(el).val() + " and text is " + $(el).next('input[type="hidden"]').val());
    });
}
```

If you want to list the values on change:

```
$('select.startID,input[type="hidden"]').change(getValues);
```

Demo (modified a bit):
http://jsfiddle.net/6ev9evew/

**NOTE**
**The updates below are not answers for the original question, but the question's author keeps posting extra questions in the comments! So the solution is above!**

**UPDATE:**

As I can understand this is what you looking for:

```
function getValues() {
    var me = this;
    $('select').each(function (idx, el) {
        console.log("Select item is " + $(el).val() + " and text is " + $(el).next('input[type="hidden"]').val());
        if (el === me) return false;
    });
}
```

So basically we stop the loop at the actual element. But it works only if you pass this function to an event handler.

**DEMO 2:** http://jsfiddle.net/6ev9evew/1/

**UPDATE 2:**

So, according to the third question, this is a version of the implementation. As I mentioned below in the comments section, there are multiple ways to implement it. This implementation uses that the  array indexes are always in order.

```
function getValues() {
    var result = [];
    var me = this; 
    $('select').each(function (idx, el) {
        var $el = $(el);
        result[10*$el.val()+idx]=("Select item is " + $el.val() + " and text is " + $el.next('input[type="hidden"]').val()+'<br />');
        if (me === el) return false;
    });
    $('#res').html(result.join(''));
}

$('select.startID,input[type="hidden"]').change(getValues);
```

**DEMO 3:**
http://jsfiddle.net/6ev9evew/2/

But you can also implement it with array.sort(fn) but than you do a second iteration on the result set.

Anyway if you have more than ten selects in your real code, don't forget to modify the multiplier at result[**10***$el.val()+idx] !

Comment: perfect, but I did get it, if you can please explain the following: each() and $(el), if it is possible to print one result after the other one, once we select 1st option it will print Text1, once we choose the second option it will print Text1 and Text2 and so on, thanks

Comment: Each iterates over all the select elements which means, that it calls the anonymous function which is passed as parameter, this function gets two parameters passed by the each function's body, these are the index of the current element (idx) and the dom element. And then we need to pass this dom element again to the jquery selector so we can access the jquery functions for this element.

Comment: is there an option to make them in order, i.e: if I choose 2 on first option, then 3 on second then 1 on third, it will display 1-Text3 2-Text1 3-Text2

Comment: Yes, you can make it order, there are multiple ways to implement that. But the implementation is depends on that you want to keep the previous feature, I mean the demo 2 or you want it as a separate implementation...

Comment: The code is getting complicated, if possible to explain these lines: `var $el = $(el);` `result[10*$el.val()+idx]`, thanks man

Comment: The var $el = $(el); is just to re-use the $(el). There are two things about this. First it is just a naming convention to me and few other folks out there to add $ prefix for the variables which are storing jQuery. Than I always know than this these variables are jQuery objects. So, $el could be anything but to make the code readable I've chosen the name $el. The second part I cache the selector because I don't want to create a jQuery object every time I'm asking for the el.

Comment: The second part, the result[10*$el.val()+idx]... The code put every line in a specific index of the result array. With this technique I used that trick that the array elements are always joining in order. So the result[0] first than the result[2] second. What you wanted to achieve is to render them in order of the values. So I'm adding them into the array at the indexes which are specified by the values. And to prevent collisions I add the original index with a lover precedence. So how I did that? I multiply by 10 the major index (10*$el.val()) and I add the minor index (+idx).

Comment: it is quite complicated, my level is a beginner, I've noticed something, if I start choosing from select box 3 then select box 2 and select box 1 (not in order), things get messed up

Comment: I forgot to modify the code on js fiddle the code at update 2 is working properly. Heres the right jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6ev9evew/7/ . Anyway I add the line breaks outside the join. That's because When you insert an item to a javascript array at a specific index and that index is larger than the array size than between the last size and the increased size it inserts undefined values :D and if you join them with the <br/> than it creates all the lines. So, I decided to put the line breaks after the each useful line which is in our case the result push

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know the value of the changed `select` (when the user selects a value on any of them) and also get the value of the `input` type `hidden` which is next to it, that's the way:

```
$('.startID').on('change', function () {
    var sel = $(this).val();
    var hid = $(this).next('input[type=hidden]').val();

    console.log('Select item is ' + sel.toString() + ' and text is ' + hid.toString());
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MelanciaUK/ztbovwrg/)

**UPDATE**

To achieve what you've asked in the comments, you can do it like this:

```
// Create two arrays to store the values.
var sel = [];
var hid = [];

$('.startID').on('change', function () {
    // Put the selected values into the arrays.
    sel.push($(this).val());
    hid.push($(this).next('input[type=hidden]').val());

    console.log(sel);
    console.log(hid);

    for (var i = 0; i < sel.length; i++) {
        console.log('Select item is ' + sel[i].toString() + ' and text is ' + hid[i].toString());
    }
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MelanciaUK/ztbovwrg/1/)

Comment: it's awesome, thanks man, if it is possible to print one result after the other one, once we select 1st option it will print Text1, once we choose the second option it will print Text1 and Text2 and so on

Comment: a small question please, how can I display the code in an inline html text? Another thing, is if I selected the 3 items, then I return to rectify one of them, it display 4 items selected, it does not change the value only